# Extract XML from .prt file using PHP but file becomes unreadable when opened with PHP

Tags: php, xml, file

I have a .prt (CAD Design File) that I need to extract some XML from using PHP. When I view this file directly in the browser, I can see the XML along with some unreadable areas. However, when I go to open it using PHP to get the XML I need from it, the file becomes mostly unreadable and the XML is no where to be found as the file looks like it was encrypted.

This is an example of what the .prt file looks like when opened directly in the browser: [File in Browser](http://www.newwebinnovations.com/part1.png)

This is an example of what the file looks like when opened using PHP: [Using PHP](http://www.newwebinnovations.com/part2.png)

This is how I am trying to open the file with PHP:

```
$handle = fopen("thePart.prt", "rb");
$contents = trim(stream_get_contents($handle));
fclose($handle);
//echo out contents to see what happens
echo $contents;
```

If I could get this file to open without doing what it is doing, I can get the XML out of it myself. How do I fix the issue that I am having? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Real Answer

Turns out that there was no problem at all with the code. The browser was just interpreting the XML tags as HTML and so the data was not displayed (PHP by default sets a content type of `text/html`). When viewing the source code, the XML was plain and visible. The XML can also be seen without viewing the source by setting the content type of the php file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

This way, the browser will just display the XML as it is, without attempting to parse it as HTML first.

### Initial Answer

Just a guess here, but it might be that you're opening the file in binary mode (the `"rb"` in your first line of code. Try opening it as a plain text file (use `"r"` instead of `"rb"`).

More likely, it's an encoding issue where PHP is trying to decode a UTF-8 file as ASCII, for instance. Since you are opening a binary file (CAD Design File is binary with a little XML, I'm assuming), PHP might be getting confused while trying to detect the encoding of the file. I would need a copy of the file to know for sure.

Try comparing the result of [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php):

```
mb_detect_encoding($contents)
```

and the actual encoding of the XML data within the .prt file. If they are different, that's how you know that PHP is using the wrong encoding. In that case, use [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert from PHP's detected encoding to that of the XML data.

Comment: Yes, I do believe that this is an encoding issue as well the more I dive further into this. When I use the php function "mb_detect_encoding" on the string that I am getting when I open my file, it says it is UTF-8. When I use the same function on the actual .prt file, it tells me that it is encoded as ASCII. I have tried to change the coding of the string to ASCII, but that is not working it seems.

Comment: Could you upload the file so I could take a look?

Comment: I think what matters is the encoding of the XML data. Copy a small portion of the readable XML from your "File in Browser" image and paste it [here](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/) to detect its encoding. Do the same with the result you get from PHP. I think that will let you know what encodings are actually in effect.

Comment: [PRT FILE](http://newwebinnovations.com/thePart.prt)  Search for UgAttributes and this will take you to the XML location that I would like to extract.

Comment: Use the exact same code as in your original post and view the source. The XML data should be there. Your browser was just interpreting the XML as HTML because that is what it requested and what the PHP script responded with.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I did not think that the browser would be doing that as I figured it should be displaying just as the actual file was. I put everything together and just finished getting the XML from the document. Thank you very much for your help.